# K-Ary Tree Implementation in Java: how to?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I've a university project about creating two classes, Tree class and Node class, to implement a k-ary tree using Java.

In the class Tree, there should be a constructor which recives as input an int that indicates the tree arity.

I've worked before with general trees and this was my result:

Class tree: *

Class node: *

I absolutely don't know where and how to start to build this project (as I don't know how to manage the arity, maybe with ArrayList?).

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the new versions of the classes, with the methods that you needed.

**Node:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node {

    public Node parent; // The parent of the current node
    public List<Node> children; // The children of the current node
    public Object info;

    public static int maxNrOfChildren; // Equal to the k-arity; 

    public Node (Object info)
    {
        this.info=info; 
        children  = new ArrayList<Node>(maxNrOfChildren);
    }

    public void addChild(Node childNode, int position)
    // You must take care so that future insertions don't override a child on i-th position
    {
        if(position>=maxNrOfChildren-1)
        {
            // Throw some error
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("this.children="+this.children);
            if(this.children.get(position)!=null)
            {
                // There is alerady a child node on this position; throw some error;
            }
            else
            {
                childNode.parent=this;
                this.children.set(position, childNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tree:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tree {
    public Node root;

    public Tree(int kArity)
    {
        Node.maxNrOfChildren=kArity;        
    }

    public void addRoot(Object info)
    {
        root=new Node(info);
        root.parent=null;
        root.children=new ArrayList<Node>(Node.maxNrOfChildren);
    }

    public void addNewNodeVasithChildOfNodeU(Node u, Object info, int i)
    {
        Node child=new Node(info);
        u.addChild(child, i);
    }

    // I've made the above two methods of type void, not Node, because
    // I see no reason in returning anything; however, you can override by calling
    //'return root;' or 'return child;'

    public int numberOfNodesInTree(Node rootNode){
        int count=0;

        count++;
        if(rootNode.children.size()!=0) {
            for(Node ch : rootNode.children)
                count=count+numberOfNodesInTree(ch);
        }

        return count;
    }

    public int numberOfNodesInTree()
    {
        return numberOfNodesInTree(this.root);
    }

    public void changeRoot(Node newRoot, int i)
    {
        Node oldRoot=this.root;
        newRoot.parent=null;
        newRoot.addChild(oldRoot, i);
        oldRoot.parent=newRoot;
        this.root=newRoot;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Tree tree=new Tree(3);
        Node a = new Node("a");
        Node b = new Node("b");
        Node c = new Node("c");

        tree.addRoot("root");
        tree.root.addChild(a,0);
        a.addChild(b,0);
        tree.root.addChild(c,1);
        System.out.println(tree.numberOfNodesInTree(tree.root));
    }
}
```

The logic is correct, but I am getting some Java-related error when I run the main method and I haven't yet figured out what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll take a look as soon as possible :)

Comment: Your code seems to be working pretty well to me, thanks a lot. Now I had to create other 11 methods for the project, when I finish I'll write there the code. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: you are welcome. if you think the answer was useful, you can mark it as accepted , or at least upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1):

this can be a starting point:

Node Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node {

    public Node parent;//the parent of the current node
    public List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();//the children of the current node
    public String name;//or any other property that the node should contain, like 'info'

    public static int maxNrOfChildren;//equal to the k-arity; 

    public Node (String nodeName)
    {
        name=nodeName; 
    }



    public void addChild(Node childNode)
    {
        if(this.children.size()>=maxNrOfChildren)
        {
            //do nothing (just don't add another node), or throw an error
        }
        else
        {
            childNode.parent=this;
            this.children.add(childNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Tree Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tree {


    public Node root = new Node("root");

    public Tree(int kArity)
    {
        Node.maxNrOfChildren=kArity;
        root.parent=null;
    }

    public void traverseTree(Node rootNode)//depth first
    {
        System.out.println(rootNode.name);
        if(rootNode.children.size()!=0)
            for(Node ch : rootNode.children)
                traverseTree(ch);
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Tree tree=new Tree(3);
        Node a = new Node("a");
        Node b = new Node("b");
        Node c = new Node("c");

        tree.root.addChild(a);
        a.addChild(b);
        tree.root.addChild(c);
        tree.traverseTree(tree.root);
    }
}
```

Please give further details about your project specifications, otherwise i can't figure out which kind of functionality you need within these classes

Comment: I need to create the following methods:

Comment: public Node<T> addRoot(T info){ ... }

Comment: public Node<T> addNewNodeVasithChildOfNodeU(Node U, T info, int i) { //the int i indicates if V is the 1st,2nd,3rd,kary son of U) return V; }

Comment: public int numberOfNodesInTree(){ ... }

Comment: public Node<T> changeRoot(T Info){ //this method insert a new root and the old one will be the i-th child of the new one }

Comment: I would be so grateful if you could help me write the code of these methods :)

Comment: perhaps the method `changeRoot()` should contain  `int i` as a parameter as well, because you said the old root should become the i-th child of the new root

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the old root would be in the first free position (null) between the other children of this old root. Because the method doesn't cointain an int i as a parameter... But sincerely I don't know

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind creating a k-array, is that this is not a conventional structure like a list or a set, the node is like an element in a linked list, it point to the n other child node and can also point to the parent, whant determine what should be the child or the parent in that sctructure is an entire different question. As for the list of child in the node you can use any structure you whant ArrayList most likely will be a good fit. The choice of a structure depend on many factors like size, how often it will be accessed does it need to be sorted etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. Hope it helps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Nary
{
public static Node root;

public static int insert(Node rootNode, int parentId, ArrayList<Node> nodeToAdd)
{
    if(rootNode == null)
        return 0;
    if(rootNode.children == null)
        rootNode.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    if(rootNode.id == parentId)
    {
        for(int i =0; i < nodeToAdd.size(); i++)
        {
            Node node = nodeToAdd.get(i);
            node.parent = rootNode;
            rootNode.children.add(node);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < rootNode.children.size(); i++)
        {
            int resultFlag = insert(rootNode.children.get(i), parentId, nodeToAdd);
            if(resultFlag == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            } 

        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void traverse(Node root)
{
    if(root == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(root.data + " " + root.id );
    for(Node child : root.children)
    {
        traverse(child);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Insertion
    root = new Node(0, "root");
    int parentId = root.id;

    Node Bread = new Node(1, "Bread");
    Node Milk = new Node(2, "Milk");
    Node Meat = new Node(3, "Meat");
    Node Eggs = new Node(4, "Eggs");

    ArrayList<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    nodeList.add(Bread);
    nodeList.add(Milk);
    nodeList.add(Meat);
    nodeList.add(Eggs);

    insert(root, parentId, nodeList);


    // Add children for Bread
    parentId = Bread.id;

    Node Bread0 = new Node(11, "Whole-Wheat");
    Node Bread1 = new Node(12, "Whole-Grain");
    Node Bread2 = new Node(13, "Italian");

    ArrayList<Node> nodeList1 = new ArrayList<Node>();
    nodeList1.add(Bread0);
    nodeList1.add(Bread1);
    nodeList1.add(Bread2);

    insert(root, parentId, nodeList1);

    Add children for Milk
    parentId = Milk.id;

    Node Milk0 = new Node(21, "Whole");
    Node Milk1 = new Node(22, "skim");
    Node Milk2 = new Node(23, "Almond");

    ArrayList<Node> nodeList2 = new ArrayList<Node>();
    nodeList2.add(Milk0);
    nodeList2.add(Milk1);
    nodeList2.add(Milk2);

    insert(root, parentId, nodeList2);

    traverse(root);

 }
 }

class Node{

int id;
String data;
Node parent;
ArrayList<Node> children;
public Node(int id, String data)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.